# What happens to records/messages during consumption when the record processing took more than 'max.poll.interval.ms'?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've below consumer settings.

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest
enable.auto.commit=true (default value)
session.timeout.ms=10000 (default value)
max.poll.interval.ms= 300000 (default value)
```

With the above configuration, let's say i have five messages( m1, m2, m3, m4 and m5) in a topic A (with only 1 partition). Now I've consumer subscribed to this topic and was able to process first two messages (m1 and m2) without any issues and committed offset.

Now, Let us say the consumer got the third message m3 and trying to process it and it took 300100 ms for processing because of some network latency. Now, as per my understanding, the offset commit will not happen because the record processing took more than max.poll.interval.ms and hence the consumer would be considered as dead and removed from the group.

Now I've two questions

1. What happens to the message m3? I mean, would it be picked in the next poll because it's offset was not committed
2. What happens to the other messages m4 and m5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expiring `max.poll.inteval.ms` without calling poll() is one of the reasons of rebalance. When rebalance starts in a consumer group, all the consumers in this consumer group are revoked. (removed from consumer list) During rebalance Kafka waits all healthy consumers to send joinGroupRequest by calling poll() until rebalance timeout (rebalance timeout equals to max.poll.interval.ms). Upon completion of joinGroupRequests of healthy consumers or rebalance timeout, Kafka assign partitions to consumers that sends joinGroupRequests.

In your case:

> What happens to the message m3? I mean, would it be picked in the next
>   poll because it's offset was not committed

**Answer:** Its process continues even after your consumer is revoked unless you have a logic to interrupt process thread in case of revoke. So all the messages returned from previous poll are processed. But offset cannot be committed. If this partition is assigned to another consumer at the result of the rebalance, then new consumer will get same messages starts from M3. So message(s) will be processed twice. When first consumer sends poll request again, that means joinGroupRequests and again rebalance will be triggered.

> What happens to the other messages m4 and m5?

**Answer:** If these messages are returned from poll() as well as m3, then result will be the same. They will be processed, but cannot be committed by the old consumer. New consumer will process messages and commit offset.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.